# Distribute macOS build of a SwiftUI app using Sign In with Apple

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, testflight

I am working on an iOS app, written in SwiftUI. I am already sharing builds with external testers using TestFlight, and it all works pretty much without problems.

Today I enabled macOS support as well using the "magic checkbox" in Xcode.

[image]

I've tested the app on my Mac, and it's good enough that I'd like to distribute this to my testers as well. Of course there is no TestFlight for macOS apps, so how do I share my build?

I created an archive, but when I try to distribute using my Developer ID and sending it to Apple's notary service I get the following errors:

[image]

So.. because my app uses Sign In with Apple I can't distribute it using a Developer ID? Does that mean I am required to send it to the Mac App Store? But it's not ready to be published to the wide open world yet!

It seems like a rather silly situation that I can find very little information about.

---

Edit:

Some additional information. First of all, it all works fine on iOS. I have created a Key for Sign In with Apple. I have also created a "Developer ID Application" Profile, and it has all the needed bits:

[image]

But yet when I try to manually select this Profile during the distribution process (instead of letting Xcode do it automatically) I see the following:

[image]

Comment: Do you have 'Sign In With Apple' configured for you Apple Developer account (`Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Keys -> Sign in With Apple`)?

Comment: Yes, and it works perfectly fine on iOS.

Comment: It looks like you have what you need.  You can try a brand-new project with the entitlement there from the beginning (instead of adding to an existing project)?  Maybe try regenerating the provisioning profile with the entitlements you need again?  Provisioning profiles, as you know, are notoriously buggy.

Comment: Shit, it looks to be an issue with Apple: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/129263.

Comment: Sucks that it doesn't work but I'm glad you found the answer.  It would be great if you could add this as an answer in case others have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it seems like it's an issue with Apple's tooling. See also https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/129263.

Nothing to do but remove Sign In with Apple (not an option for me), or simply wait for Apple to fix this :(